# React native current location asking for permission in AndroidManifiest.xml ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, but already added

Tags: android, react-native

I have already added ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION but still getting error of

`Looks like the app doesn't have the permission to access location.
Add the following line to your app's AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

[image]

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

Please Help.

Comment: share your manifest file

Comment: in which version of Android are you testing?

Comment: @SunilSoni Android 7.0

Comment: @Nilu updated answer please check and if need full .xml file will update you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add **`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`** and **`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`** permission in manifest

make sure you have added the permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

if you are targetting android api 23 and above than you have to ask **[run-time permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)**

**Because** Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

**SAmple code**

```
                 String permission = android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, permission)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.
                        checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Toast.makeText(SearchCityClass.this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SearchCityClass.this, new String[]
                            {permission}, requestCode);

                }
```

Comment: Can you please explain me how to ask for runtime permission ?

Comment: But i am actually using  `android:targetSdkVersion="22" `

Comment: @KirankumarDafda if your `android:targetSdkVersion="22"` than may you have problem in api 23 and above beacuse above marsh mallow and noghut user grant permission while app is running not while installing

Comment: Thank you very much your code is working fine in real device. (Still error in emulator but, it's ok for me)

Comment: @KirankumarDafda happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

On devices before SDK version 23, the permissions are automatically granted if they appear in the manifest, so check and the request should always be true.

If a user has previously turned off a permission that you prompt for, the OS will advise your app to show a rationale for needing the permission. The optional rationale argument will show a dialog prompt only if necessary - otherwise, the normal permission prompt will appear.

```
    import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
    async function requestCameraPermission() {
    try {
          const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          {
          'title': 'Location Permission Permission',
           'message': 'App needs access to your Location ' +
               '.'
          }
          )
       if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("You can use the Location")
       } else {
         console.log("Location permission denied")
     }
} catch (err) {
console.warn(err)
}
}
```