# Getting never_ask_again by default on react native when I ask for location

Tags: react-native, permissions, geolocation, android-permissions

This is the function that asks for permission and it logs to the console: never_ask_again automatically

```js
requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          title: "Cool Photo App Camera Permission",
          message:
            "Cool Photo App needs access to your camera " +
            "so you can take awesome pictures.",
          buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
          buttonNegative: "Cancel",
          buttonPositive: "OK"
        }
      );
      console.log(await 
    PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };
```

this is my androidManifest.xml

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Are you using Android SDK target API below 23 in your app? you just need to add permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` for target API greater than 23. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48108919/react-native-current-location-asking-for-permission-in-androidmanifiest-xml-acce).